# array contents that are linked list

Tags: php, data-structures

I have this question to make a function to read students information in multiple schools and store them in array of schools each student has multiple attributes (age,name..) 
the attributes should be linked list !

how to make the attributes as linked list ?

```
<? php
function read_info() {

$schools = array();

$position= count($school);

$schools[$position] = array () ; }
```

Comment: How about http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why would you need linked list here? Surely you can use it, but you are not going to use dynamic operations on that list, aren't you? You can use associative array for that. The data is static.

But, for simple php implementation of linked list, you may check this: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/07/24/php-arrays-or-linked-lists/

Comment: thnx but what my question is how to put many linked lists inside one superior array ,,not just linked list implementation